# Содержимое одного тега в другой тег в другом файле

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Необходимо по клику на `<div class="shop-el-footer" > содержимое тега <div class="shop-el-header"> засунуть в value  <textarea name="text" placeholder="Ваше сообщение"></textarea>`

```
файл shop.html
    <div class="ratio-inner ratio-1-2">
                            <div class="ratio-content">
                                <div class="shop-el-header">Светильник</div>
                                <img tabindex="0" src="img/box.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="shop-el-footer" onclick="window.open('shop-buy.html')">Заказать</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    файл shop-buy.html
        <textarea name="text" placeholder="Ваше сообщение"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте **Local Storage**

**Local Storage** - Значения существуют независимо от закрытия окна или вкладки. 
Значения совместно используются всеми окнами и вкладками, выполняющимися на том же источнике. 
Лимит на данные для **Local Storage** составляет 5 Mb. Данное поведение может зависеть от браузера.

```
    <!-- tmp1.html Отправляем данные -->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>send</title>    
        <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("button").click(function () {
                    window.localStorage.mytext = $("#t1").val();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>Отправить</button>
        <input type="text" id="t1" value="test"/>
    </body>
    </html>

<!-- tmp2.html Получаем данные -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>get</title>
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                 $("#t1").val(window.localStorage.mytext);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Принять</button>
    <input type="text" id="t1"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//получаем элемент, на который вешаем событие click
var shopElFooter = document.querySelector('.shop-el-footer');
//вешаем событие click
shopElFooter.addEventListener('click', function() {
  //получаем элемент из которого будем брать содержимое
  var shopElHeader = document.querySelector('.shop-el-header');
  //получаем содержимое
  var shopElHeaderContent = shopElHeader.innerHTML;
  //получаем элемент, в который вставляем содержимое
  var textArea = document.querySelector('textarea');
  //вставляем содержимое
  textArea.value = shopElHeaderContent;
})
```